# Has there been a football (soccer) player with first name, full stop and first letter of surname on the kit?

Tags: football

For some reason I assume to have seen someone with the name in this style on the shirt, but I cannot remember the name. For example, Lionel Messi would be:

LIONEL.M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I've spent a couple of minutes on a football jersey website and I've managed to find one example: [Alberto Moreno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alberto_Moreno).

[image: Alberto M. jersey]

I'm not sure if he's the only who chose to use this peculiar way of writing the name.

Answer (score -2):

This happens when multiple players have the same last name, so their first name initial is added to distinguish them.

That being said, you usually see the first letter of the first name coming before the last name. But that's likely due to cultural reason and how in most western countries, you say your first then last name. In other cultures, it could be the order in OP's question.

Anyway, here are 2 picture of Hazard brothers (Eden and Thorgan) playing for Belgium:
[image: Eden & Thorgan Hazard 1]
[image: Eden & Thorgan Hazard 2]

Since they obviously have the same last name, the first letter of their first names are added to distinguish them.

Lukaku brothers used to play together also for Belgium, here is a picture of Romelu Lukaku in the same format:
[image: Rumolu Lukaku]

But also note that players don't have to have their last name on the jersey. Some opt in for a first name (ex, Darwin Nunuez) and some a nickname (ex, Pele), so it's possible a player could opt in for such a format voluntarily.

Comment: I think in case of brothers and namesakes the expected way to write is to put a period *after* the first letter of the last name, e.g. THORGAN H. The OP is looking for a full stop *between* the first and last names, e.g. THORGAN.H, which is a tiny bit less usual, I guess.